# Can I use decltype() to avoid code duplication in explicit template instantiations?

Tags: c++, templates, code-duplication, decltype, explicit-instantiation

I have a long template function declaration:

```
template <typename T> void foo(lots ofargs, goin here, andeven more, ofthese arguments, they just, dont stop);
```

with no overloads. and I want to explicitly instantiate it. I can write (say for `T` = `int`):

```
template void foo<int>(lots ofargs, goin here, andeven more, ofthese arguments, they just, dont stop);
```

But I really don't want to copy that long declaration. I would have *liked* to be able to say something like:

```
template <typename T> using bar = decltype(foo<T>);
```

and then:

```
template bar<int>;
```

Now, the first line compiles (GCC 4.9.3), but the second line doesn't. Can I make it work somehow? Or can I use `decltype()` some other way to avoid copying the declaration for the instantiation?

**Note:** I intentially used an example in which you can't deduce the type from just the arguments, since I want any solution to support this case as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. From [temp.explicit]:

> The syntax for explicit instantiation is:
>       *explicit-instantiation*:
>           extern<sub>opt</sub> `template` *declaration*
>
> [...] If the explicit instantiation is for a function or member function, the *unqualified-id* in the declaration shall be either a *template-id* or, where all template arguments can be deduced, a
>   *template-name* or *operator-function-id*. *[ Note:* The declaration may declare a *qualified-id*, in which case the
>   *unqualified-id* of the *qualified-id* must be a *template-id*. *—end note ]*

We need a declaration. Let's pretend we're starting with:

```
template <class T> void foo(T ) { }
```

We can explicitly specialize via just:

```
template void foo<char>(char );   // template-id
template void foo(int );          // or just template-name, if the types can be deduced
```

This is the same as having written:

```
using Fc = void(char );
using Fi = void(int );

template Fc foo<char>;
template Fi foo;
```

Which is the same as having written:

```
template <class T> using F = decltype(foo<T> );

template F<char> foo<char>;
template F<int> foo;
```

Basically, the reason that `template bar<int>` doesn't work is that it's not a declaration. You need the name too.

Comment: I'm editing the question so as to make sure you can't deduce the template argument for the function arguments, which is what I was actually interested in. I just sprinkled a T t for good measure, didn't mean for you to use it... If your answer is still relevant, then great.

Comment: @einpoklum That isn't remotely clear from the question, and why do you think my answer isn't relevant?

Comment: I didn't say it was irrelevant, I just had the sense (before your last edit) that you might be relying on it more than you actually are.